# Linux RHEL 7 - Shell Script - Can execute command separately but cannot execute inside a script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, script

I have a simple script use to install a package under cust privilege like this (command changed for security)
installScript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
patch -i <package-name> << EOF
n
EOF
```

the purpose of this script is for automate enter N (No) when prompt "Are you sure? (Y/n)" for testing purpose.
The permission of this file is

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 cust root  66 Jul 25 15:06 installScript.sh
```

However,
When I execute this command using

```
./installScript.sh
or 
sh /home/cust/installScript.sh
```

I get the permission denied. But by executing `patch` command manually, I can get things working out normally without any issues. Is there anything that need to be configured?

Comment: This might help: [Patch: auto answer no](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/181447/74329)

Comment: If the script starts with `#!/bin/bash` it is wrong to use `sh` to execute it. Use `bash` or better still just run it directly

Answer (score 1):

It's a permission problem with your group being "root".
You'll have to `sudo ./installScript.sh`

Or, you can `sudo chown cust:cust ./installScript.sh` and not need `sudo` to run.

Also, you could use [xdotool](https://rhel.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/xdotool-3.20150503.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) for the input.

```
#!/bin/bash
patch -i <package-name> &&
xdotool keydown n
```